# Using multiple filter functions in google sheets elastically

Tags: google-sheets

In a Google spreadsheet, I have a summary sheet were I am importing information from multiple sheets. One of my filter function looks like the following:

=Filter(Sheet2!A14:A27, (Sheet2!K14:K27="Y") + (Sheet2!K14:K27="R"))

I have a multiple Filter functions like this one. The problem I am facing is that I have to assign a static number of rows for the result of this function but the result is very dynamic (could be 1 row or even 15 rows).

I have been searching exhaustively but couldnt find a good way to do it elastically so that the results of all Filter functions are just appended (with perhaps an empty row/header row between each of the results).

One solution that someone gave on one of the forums was to assign static number of rows to each and hide the empty rows using a script which did not seem a very clean solution (but I may have to fallback on that)

Also, I thought of using scripts but if I understand it correctly, scripts can only be 'triggered' from menus, onOpen, onEdit etc. which may also not be very intuitive (one has to reload the spreadsheet to see any change in case of onOpen(), etc.)

Using custom functions would again cause the same problem because custom functions run on a specific cell (and we dont know which cell since we are trying to make this dynamic)

Happy to hear any thoughts!

Comment: You can just concatenate the results of several filter operations. e.g. `={Filter(Sheet1!A14:A27, (Sheet1!K14:K27="Y") + (Sheet1!K14:K27="R"));A1;Filter(Sheet2!A14:A27, (Sheet2!K14:K27="Y") + (Sheet2!K14:K27="R"))}`. A1 is just an empty cell used to seperate the results.

Comment: btw. custom functions can work on many cells and return many cells as a result just like Filter can.

Comment: Thanks SpiderPig! Didnt know that! I am trying this out (though its now becoming too long given all the concatenations but will try to find a way to modularise it)

Comment: On your second comment, when I was trying to use copyTo() in a custom function, to copy a cell's value, it gave me a permissions error. I then read in the documentation that custom functions cant really be used to "write" to another cell. But maybe I could have put the entire result in an array and then just output that in that cell so it automatically gets to other cells (just like Filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always pass the cells/ranges you work on into the custom function instead of reading them within the function. Also try not to write directly but instead return a result. That way the spreadsheet will automatically update correctly and you won't need any permissions.
Here is an example

```
function myFilter(values1, values2) {
  return values1.filter(function(v, i) {
    return values2[i][0] === "Y" || values2[i][0] === "R";
  });
}
```

and then do

```
={myFilter(Sheet1!A14:A27,Sheet1!K14:K27);A1;myFilter(Sheet2!A14:A27,Sheet2!K14:K27)}
```

still get's a little long though. But you could also save intermediary results in different cells and then join the results together. Or write a filter function that can take an arbitrary number of ranges as arguments.
Can you give some more examples of what those filter functions look like. Maybe there is a better way to modularise/shorten it.

Answer (score 8):

Here is how to stack multiple columns.

{A:A;B:B;C:C}

Here is how to stack multiple filters.

{Filter1;Filter2;Filter3}

Here is how to stack multiple filters with headers.

{"Header1";Filter1;"Header2";Filter2;"Header3";Filter3}

Comment: Not working for me. Trying multiple filters in 1 formula