# Multiple/Nested FILTER functions in Google Sheets?

Tags: database, function, google-sheets

I had asked a question previously that involved a FILTER function in Google Sheets, and trying to have data from a database output to another sheet in a more readable format.

If you would like to check out that question, you can find it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77351763/how-to-append-specific-ranges-of-data-to-the-end-of-other-data-in-google-sheet)

I would like to expand on that question and ask if it is possible to use a FILTER function that outputs data in "layers."

I have a data set that resembles something like this:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID | NAME | BIG LOC | MAIN LOC | SEC LOC | THI LOC |
| :--: | :---------: | :-----------------------------: | :---------: | :-------: | :--------: |
| #1 | HAMMER | TOOL ROOM - CART 1 - DRAWER 1 | TOOL ROOM | CART 1 | DRAWER 1 |
| #2 | DRILL | TOOL ROOM - CART 1 - DRAWER 2 | TOOL ROOM | CART 1 | DRAWER 2 |
| #3 | WRENCH | TOOL ROOM - WALL | TOOL ROOM | WALL |  |
| #4 | DRIVER | TOOL ROOM - WALL - CAGE 1 | TOOL ROOM | WALL | CAGE 1 |

Column C is a TextJoin of Columns D-F.

My data set is much more complex than that, but the idea is there in the table. If you want to see a picture of part of my current data set you can see that [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl8Wz.png)

Currently, my database is on SHEET 1, but I have made a more readable version on SHEET 2 where I use Data Validation to make a dropdown that allows you to select locations from COLUMN C in the table above. Using that dropdown as my reference, I use a FILTER function to output all of the tool IDs that are located in those areas.

For example, (based on the table above) my dropdown options would be as follows:

| DROPDOWN OPTIONS |
| --- |
| TOOL ROOM - CART 1 - DRAWER 1 |
| TOOL ROOM - CART 1 - DRAWER 2 |
| TOOL ROOM - WALL |
| TOOL ROOM - WALL CAGE 1 |

Unfortunately, that will only give me the tool IDs that fit that exact location.

I am trying to see if it is possible that I can have a FILTER function that would list ALL of the tool IDs that are located in the TOOL ROOM but have a separator that tells me these tools are on Cart 1, these tools are on the Wall, etc.

For example, I would like to pick TOOL ROOM on the drop down and have the output look something like this:

| ID | NAME | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TOOL ROOM |  |  |
| CART 1 |  |  |
| DRAWER 1 |  |  |
| #1 | HAMMER | 1 |
| DRAWER 2 |  |  |
| #2 | DRILL | 1 |
| WALL |  |  |
| #3 | WRENCH | 1 |
| CAGE 1 |  |  |
| #4 | DRIVER | 1 |

So basically I had a sort of "nested" or "multiple" FILTER function in mind.

Any help would greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

I have tried using various IF functions, and tried playing around with FILTER functions even tried separating my data into multiple sheets.

I found someone with a sort of similar issue, but my data is always expanding and contracting, so I can't do a static number, and I'm not sure how to implement a header inside of the FILTER functions in the way that I am trying to do. You can see that question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874457/using-multiple-filter-functions-in-google-sheets-elastically)

EDIT EDIT EDIT

[HERE IS A SAMPLE SHEET I WAS ASKED TO MAKE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FB-2S7Q6DQsMTTRMXn_gzswIJL5MXvcnrTQWeZwI660/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: Ah, okay, I will set one up right now, thank you! I was actually concerned about sharing the sheet.

Comment: I added the link to the bottom of my question that has the sample sheet! Thank you for pointing that out to me.

Comment: Your expected output(tab) provides *instructions* instead of showcasing what the output actually is. Condense/limit your database tab data if needed for testing purposes here & add the ideal expected output ***manually*** so that it gives a clear picture for us all to work it out

Comment: Okay, I apologize. I will try to update it right now.

Comment: I updated the sample spreadsheet and limited it exclusively to ACI and manually made the other sheet look like what I am hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Added [one possible solution here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FB-2S7Q6DQsMTTRMXn_gzswIJL5MXvcnrTQWeZwI660/edit#gid=1526635303) for you to test out:*

```js
=reduce(tocol(,1),unique(filter(DATABASE!I:I,DATABASE!J:J=B2)),lambda(a,c,ifna(vstack(a,regexreplace(c,"(^.*? - )",),filter(DATABASE!F:H,DATABASE!I:I=c)))))
```

→ *conditional formatting added to columns G,H,I to auto-highlight the headers dynamically*

```js
=len($G1)*isblank($H1)*isblank($I1)
```

[image]

Comment: Dude! You are a rockstar!I am getting a formula parse error when I attempt to implement it into my main sheet. Let me see if I can troubleshoot it.

Comment: Like I said, you are a rock star! That worked. I can't get the conditional formatting to work, but I will keep troubleshooting it to get it to work. Again, you are awesome! Thank you!